# Change button status (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I wanna make twitter like microblog site which other users can follow my posts.

For that i made page with all currently registered users. In front of each name there is button to follow/unfollow user. (Like in Twitter)

[image: Follow User Page]

View -

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Users";
}
@model MembershipUserCollection

@foreach (MembershipUser item in Model)
{
if(User.Identity.Name != item.UserName)
{

     <li>@item.UserName 
        <span id="sp-@item.UserName"><input id="@item.UserName" name="submit" type="submit" value="Follow" class="follow-user fg-button ui-state-default"/></span> 
     </li>
}

} 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".follow-user").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).attr("id");
        var spid = '#sp-' + data;
        var btnid = '#' + data;
        var val = $(this).attr('value');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "User/FollowUser",
            data: { id: data },
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                if (val == 'Follow') {
                    $(btnid).attr('value', 'Unfollow');
                }
                else {
                    $(btnid).attr('value', 'Follow');
                }

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller -

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(Membership.GetAllUsers());
}

public void FollowUser(string id)
{
    ViewData["test"] = "test";
    var n = FollowingUser.CreateFollowingUser(0);
    n.FollowingId = id;
    n.FollowerId = User.Identity.Name;
    string message = string.Empty;
    var list = new List<FollowingUser>();

    list = (from a in db.FollowingUsers where a.FollowerId == User.Identity.Name && a.FollowingId == id select a).ToList();

    if (list.Count() == 0)
    {

        try
        {
            db.AddToFollowingUsers(n);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            message = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    else 
    {
        db.DeleteObject((from a in db.FollowingUsers where a.FollowerId == User.Identity.Name select a).FirstOrDefault());
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

FollowingUsers Table -

[image: FollowingUsers Table]

Now i wanna change button status on page load checking database whether he is already followed or not.

Ex- If user already followed it should display like below.

[image: Unfollow]

Answer (score 2):

When you show this view to a user where this button is displayed, Load the status also, if the person is following or not.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model  = new MemberShipViewModel();
    //We check here if the logged in user is already following the user being viewd

    foreach(var member in  Membership.GetAllUsers())
    {

      var user = (from a in db.FollowingUsers where a.FollowerId == User.Identity.Name && a.FollowingId == member.UserName select a).FirstOrDefault();
     model.Members.Add(new Member{UserName = member.UserName,IsFollowing=user!=null});
    }
    //This line will remove the logged in user.   
    model.Members.Remove(model.Members.First(m=>m.UserName==User.Identity.Name)); 


    return view(model);


}
```

In your index view model, you need to make some changes.

```
 @model MemberShipViewModel

 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {

 <li>@item.UserName 

if(!item.IsFollowing)
{

    <span id="sp-@item.UserName"><input id="@item.UserName" name="submit" type="submit" value="Follow" class="follow-user fg-button ui-state-default"/></span> 
 }
 else
 {

    <span id="sp-@item.UserName"><input id="@item.UserName" name="submit" type="submit" value="Follow" class="unfollow-user fg-button ui-state-default"/></span> 

}


 </li>
```

}

$(".follow-user").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).attr("id");
        var spid = '#sp-' + data;
        var btnid = '#' + data;
        var val = $(this).attr('value');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "User/FollowUser",
            data: { id: data },
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                if (val == 'Follow') {
                    $(btnid).attr('value', 'Unfollow');
                }
                else {
                    $(btnid).attr('value', 'Follow');
                }

            }
        });
    });

You need to write some javascript now. Nobody is going to write full software for you.
Seems you are missing very basic programming skills.

cheers

Comment: Do i have to make model also ?

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain this line ?
SomeRepository.IsFollowing(LoggedInUser.Id,id)

What are SomeRepository, IsFollowing, LoggedInUser.Id and id ?

Comment: That is the class where you will be checking if the logged in user is following the user being viewed or if you  want to write your code here, you can.

Comment: Just my bit of addictional noise: I don't like having explicit ifs in the view, I prefer to add a property in the model (or add the label in ViewData)

Comment: Hmm. Can some one gimme clear controller, view and model i required to do above task ?
I couldn't get Parminder's code working :/

Comment: This will be list of users and there will be buttons to follow each. So how can i pass id when page load ?